# How to identify a fragment from it's button's xml onClick view?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-view, android-button

I have some fragments that are being added programatically with differing tags. Each holds a button with an xml onClick that gets passed a view. How do I identify which fragment was clicked from that view? Code is below.

NewFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_fragment, container, false);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    int index = bundle.getInt("index");
    tv.setText(Integer.toString(index));

    return view;
}
```

Activity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    for (int loop = 0; loop < 4; loop++) {
        NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", loop);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
    //tag set to value of loop here
        ft.add(R.id.new_fragment, fragment, Integer.toString(loop));
    }
    ft.commit();
}

public void toggleEdit(View view) {
  //How do I find clicked fragment?
  }
```

new_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/test">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:text="Test"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Button in question is below -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/edit"
        android:onClick="toggleEdit"
        android:id="@+id/edit_button"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have your Fragment define an interface which your activity implements.  Give that interface a method with a string parameter, and onClick, pass in the current Fragment's tag.

See this guide on Fragment communication for more detail http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading through it now. I was hoping the answer would be something simpler. For instance I was trying to setId inside NewFragment and recover it from onClick's view. I couldn't get that working though.

Comment: Yeah. Interfaces are the correct way to communicate.  Any other way would be quite a hack, and I wouldn't expect it to work well or be easy.

Comment: Interfaces are actually very very easy to do though.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. How do I find the current fragment's tag to pass it on?

Comment: inside a method of the fragment, call String tag = this.getTag();  If you are inside an anonymous class like an OnClickListener, you might need to call String tag = MyFragment.this.getTag();

Comment: I have an interface method implemented inside my activity, but it requires the string I'm looking for (it's an index) as an argument. That method gets executed during the fragment's onAttach (it currently just writes the string to log). At that point, it's all going according to plan. The problem crops up when I need that string again later on - during the onClick. The best I've been able to do is get only the latest value, from the last fragment that was created.